# How the users can create sub-users in SugarCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm

Admin can able to create users. After creating, the user will get system generated password and they can login with that password and can do some task. After login, I want to create some more users and they can also will have access to modules.

How can I do it in SugarCRM?

Comment: You make the first set of users System Administrators or assign them Roles wherein they can manage User records. Then they'll be able to create Users just as your first Admin User did.

Comment: Hi Matthew, If I give the users to Admin permission, they will have all the permission like my first admin. I don't need like that. The thing is, The user would have the permission to add users only. So that they can interact themselves. For example, "SuperAdmin->SubAdmin(Can add users only)->Created users need login page(need interaction with the subadmin like chatting, video chatting)"

Comment: I need access "User Management" section to the subadmin

Comment: You can create a role to allow some non-admin users to have admin access to User Management without giving them access to other admin tools.

Comment: Good idea. But I am seeing module access only in the role management section. There is no option to give access to the usre management section. How can I do it? Please guide me or refer some tutorials to read about the file structure.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realize the Users module wasn't available to the normal ACL/Roles control in CE. You could probably make it available by hacking the module, but the easier route would probably be to look into an add-on called Security Suite. It may handle this better - https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/docs/securitysuite/ If not, your answer is to hack into the User ACLs or purchase SugarCRM Professional which does allow User Management as a Role.